# How to check if operator<< is defined for a class?

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, type-traits

I want to use type traits to check if operator `<<` is defined for some classes.

So I've defined 2 classes `A` and `B` which are similar but the operator `<<` is overloaded only for `A`.

To do that I am making use of `boost::is_detected`.

The running code is the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_detected.hpp>
class A
{
  public:
    std::string name;
    int64_t age;
    bool b;

};

class B
{
  public:
    std::string name;
    int64_t age;
    bool b;

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& destination, const A& type)
{
    return destination << "name=" << type.name << ", age=" << int(type.age)<<std::endl;
}


template <typename T>
using has_operator_insertion_check = decltype(void(&std::decay_t<T>::operator<<));

template <typename T>
using has_operator_insertion = boost::is_detected<has_operator_insertion_check, T>;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_operator_insertion_v = has_operator_insertion<T>::value;


int main()
{
  A a, b;
  a.name = "Ciaooooo";
  a.age = 65536;
  a.b = true;
  std::cout<<"A has operator '<<'? "<<has_operator_insertion_v<A><<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"B has operator '<<'? "<<has_operator_insertion_v<B><<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However, this is not working and the output I am getting is:

```
A has operator '<<'? 0
B has operator '<<'? 0
```

Why am I getting identical results?

Comment: Do you can about _any_ `operator<<` overload, or specifically `operator<<(std::ostream&, T)`?

Comment: My priority is for `<<`. Anything further is appreciated but not necessary

Comment: -> `decltype(void(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::decval<T>()));`

Comment: Both result is false as there are no `A::operator <<`.

Comment: HI Jarod, from the output I can see that too, I am sking why and how to do it

Comment: Free function `::operator<<(std::ostream&, const A&)` is NOT a member function  `A::operator <<`. Above `decltype` should detect your function. Not sure if it is sufficient for your case.

Comment: Since this is tagged boost, `Boost Type Erasure` has `ostreamable` predefined for `operator<<`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/predef.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& destination, const A& type)
```

is a free function, not a member function and

```
decltype(void(&std::decay_t<T>::operator<<));
```

only checks for the presence of a member function.

You can rewrite your type trait to work with member and non-member output operators like

```
// false case
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_operator_insertion_check : std::false_type {};

// partial specialization, 
// if std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>() is valid then true
template <typename T>
struct has_operator_insertion_check<T, std::void_t<decltype((std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_operator_insertion_v = has_operator_insertion_check<T>::value;
```

You can see this working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e751372006b6cd87).

Comment: Just a note: `std::void_t` is defined in C++17 or later, not in C++14 for example